# format numbers in Y-axis at Angular Chart.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I'm working with angular chart js and trying to format scaleLabels on Y axis. I did find couple solutions on forum how I can impact on labels thru this line in my Chart.js `

> scaleLabel: "<%=value%>"

for example, if I set value100%, I'll get result like 0.000000, but what if i need to leave just one number after comma?

this is my screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is

> scaleLabel: "<%=Math.abs(value).toFixed(1)%>"